# Subquery returns more than one value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, subquery

I'm trying to use a stored procedure I wrote that is supposed to create a new project in a "Project" table. It also checks to see if there is a saved project in a "Saved Project" table with the same ID and deletes it upon successful creation.

It's also supposed to check whether the user_id passed has permission to actually create a project( i.e. isn't a standard user).

Here is the stored procedure:

```
USE [BugMate_DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[create_project]    Script Date: 2020-07-08 11:05:30 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[create_project]
    @project_name NVARCHAR(40),
    @date_started DATETIME,
    @project_description NVARCHAR(400),
    @project_status NVARCHAR(40),
    @project_active BIT,
    @next_iteration_date DATETIME,
    @created_by_userid INT,
    @project_leader_id INT,
    @save_id INT = NULL
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
    IF (SELECT TOP 1 roleid from user_info WHERE userid = @created_by_userid) = 'SDU'
    BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('User does not have permission to do this action. Please contact a manager or administrator to resolve this issue.', 16, 1)
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO project(project_name, date_started, project_description, project_status, project_active, next_iteration_date, created_by_userid, project_leader_id)
            VALUES (@project_name, @date_started, @project_description, @project_status, @project_active, @next_iteration_date, @created_by_userid, @project_leader_id)

            IF @@ERROR <> 0
            BEGIN
                    RAISERROR('Project creation insert failed.', 16, 1)
            END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF @save_id != NULL
                    BEGIN
                        IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 save_id FROM saved_project WHERE save_id = @save_id)
                        BEGIN
                                DELETE FROM saved_project WHERE save_id = @save_id
                        END
                    END         
                END
        END

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
                RAISERROR('Error creating project', 16, 1)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
                INSERT INTO project_member(userid, project_number)
                VALUES (@created_by_userid, (SELECT project_number FROM project WHERE created_by_userid = @created_by_userid))
        END
END
```

The problem is that I am getting this error when execute my SP:

*Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure create_project, Line 48
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

I'm not sure why any of my sub queries would be returning multiple values.

Here are the values I am trying to pass:

```
USE [BugMate_DB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[create_project]
        @project_name = N'Test',
        @date_started = N'12/25/2015 12:00:00 AM',
        @project_description = N'This is a test.',
        @project_status = N'InDevelopment',
        @project_active = 1,
        @next_iteration_date = N'12/25/2015 12:00:00 AM',
        @created_by_userid = 19,
        @project_leader_id = 19,
        @save_id = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I have tried using "TOP 1" to try and get a single value back but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

As far as I can tell this isn't an issue of joins either.

I'm new to SQL Server so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The very last statement in your procedure is the problem. And the comment "... doesn't seem to be what I'm look for" is something meaningful to you and no one else. The logic you want to use is most likely incorrect - surely the same person can create more than one project over time. And you cannot compare anything to NULL using the equality operator. You must use ISNULL for that.

Comment: A little mind-reading - is project_number an identity column?

Comment: And another flaw - using TOP without an order by clause will only limit the number of rows in a resultset. It does NOT guarantee that any particular row is selected. You should replace that with EXISTS - but that may not be logically correct either.

Comment: project_number is the identity column. I should clarify that the same person can create multiple projects, the check  " IF (SELECT TOP 1 roleid from user_info WHERE userid = @created_by_userid) = 'SDU' ", is there to verify the user's permission level. Thanks for your help @SMor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this

```
IF ( SELECT TOP 1 roleid from user_info WHERE userid = @created_by_userid ) = 'SDU'
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ( 'User does not have permission to do this action. Please contact a manager or administrator to resolve this issue.', 16, 1 )
END
```

To

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE userid = @created_by_userid AND roleid = 'SDU' )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ( 'User does not have permission to do this action. Please contact a manager or administrator to resolve this issue.', 16, 1 )
END
```

**Edit**: Include explicit role access.

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE userid = @created_by_userid AND roleid IN ( 'SDU', 'MNG', 'ADM ' ) )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ( 'User does not have permission to do this action. Please contact a manager or administrator to resolve this issue.', 16, 1 )
END
```

**Update**:

```
USE [BugMate_DB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[create_project]
    @project_name NVARCHAR(40),
    @date_started DATETIME,
    @project_description NVARCHAR(400),
    @project_status NVARCHAR(40),
    @project_active BIT,
    @next_iteration_date DATETIME,
    @created_by_userid INT,
    @project_leader_id INT,
    @save_id INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @err INT = 0;
    DECLARE @output TABLE ( project_number INT );

    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE userid = @created_by_userid AND roleid IN ( 'SDU', 'MNG', 'ADM ' ) )
    BEGIN
            RAISERROR ( 'User does not have permission to do this action. Please contact a manager or administrator to resolve this issue.', 16, 1 );
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO project (
            project_name, date_started, project_description, project_status, project_active, next_iteration_date, created_by_userid, project_leader_id
        )
        OUTPUT inserted.project_number INTO @output
        VALUES (
            @project_name, @date_started, @project_description, @project_status, @project_active, @next_iteration_date, @created_by_userid, @project_leader_id
        );

        -- Capture error value.
        SET @err = @@ERROR;

        IF @err <> 0
        BEGIN
                RAISERROR ( 'Project creation insert failed.', 16, 1 );
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN

            IF @save_id IS NULL
            BEGIN

                IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM saved_project WHERE save_id IS NULL )
                BEGIN
                    DELETE FROM saved_project WHERE save_id IS NULL;
                END
            
            END         

        END

    END

    IF @err <> 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ( 'Error creating project', 16, 1 );
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO project_member ( 
            userid, project_number
        )
        VALUES (
            @created_by_userid, 
            ( SELECT project_number FROM @output )
        );

    END

END
```

Comment: I tried this out but I should clarify what I'm trying to achieve with this check. I want to have 3 types of user's with different permission levels. From lowest to highest is: SDU, MNG, ADM or Standard User, Manager, Administrator. I want to check that the user trying to create the project is NOT a Standard User because they do not have permission to create a project. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Assuming I understood what you stated, check out my Edit above.

Comment: I have changed my code to what you suggested and I think your answer makes sense but I am still getting the original error. I think the problem is further down my code somewhere because if I pass the user_id of a user that does not have permission to create a project it triggers the error message saying they don't have permission and the statement terminates; however, if they do have permission the error remains the same saying the sub-query returns more than one value.

Comment: I think I found your issue, @Chris. Check out my update to your SP.

Comment: Yes this fixed it thank you! @TAirlines below put me on this track as well. My last statement was returning all of the values in my "project" table, hence the "returning more than one value". I used " IDENT_CURRENT('project') ". I was getting confused because I assumed the projects were not getting created because I was getting the sub-query error, however it appears they were and the error was on the statement you fixed above. I'm not sure which one is better practice but your answer makes more sense to me so I will use that one. Thanks again!

Comment: Using INSERT/OUTPUT is the recommended way for capturing a specifically inserted identity value. You can also use @@IDENTITY immediately after insert, however, @@IDENTITY and IDENT_CURRENT are not reliable if your DB has a lot of write traffic. Stick with INSERT/OUTPUT.

Comment: One more note is that I would set @@ERROR to a variable vs continuously referencing @@ERROR as it's a global value (just like @@IDENTITY) and *will* get changed. I've updated the SP above to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Please compare the `NULL` values using `IS NULL` like below:

```
IF @save_id IS NULL
```

or

```
IF @save_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for this I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this type of query before

```
INSERT INTO project_member(userid, project_number)
VALUES (@created_by_userid, 
(SELECT project_number FROM project WHERE created_by_userid = @created_by_userid))
```

I would do either

```
INSERT INTO project_member(userid, project_number)
VALUES (@created_by_userid, @project_id)
```

if I were just inserting 2 values.

If inserting many values I would do `SELECT` and not `VALUES`.

If I were inserting maybe more that 1 row of values:

```
INSERT INTO project_member(userid, project_number)
SELECT created_by_userid, project_number FROM project
WHERE created_by_userid = @created_by_userid
```

Im just guessing since that is about line 46

Also, what sacse said about `IF (@save_id IS NULL)`

maybe there is an answer in there someplace

Comment: This wasn't quite my issue but it put me on the right track. Thanks for your help! The answer is above.